# Возможно ли в Qt5 при подключении к QTcpServer сразу передать идентификационную информацию о новом клиенте?

Tags: c++, qt, сокет, qt5, qtcpsocket

на сервере при установлении нового соединения

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(newConnection()), SLOT(slot_newConnection()));
```

в слоте **slot_newConnection()** можно было определить название соединения клиента

```
QSslSocket *client = dynamic_cast<QSslSocket*>(this->nextPendingConnection());
Q_ASSERT(client);
QString name = client->someFooGetParam("name"); //получить имя
```

Возможно такое средствами Qt5? Или же обязательно надо передавать после удачного соединения?

Comment: А что значит "название соединения клиента" ? ну т.е. что вы хотите там увидеть (ип адрес клиента, данные его станции, имя компа или что-то еще?)

Comment: @goldstar_labs пусть будет даже имя компа. Значит что переводя на хуманридбл вариант "К серверу стукнулся клиент Вася", как-то так.

Comment: я не силен в QT, но максимум информации, хранящейся в TCP/IP это ип и порт (`peerAddress()` & `peerPort()`), но попробуйте `peerName()`. Чтобы получить имя хоста надо делать запрос к арп таблице (IP => hostname) или передавать имя хоста по уже установленному соединению на сервер. Без дополнительных запросов вы можете писать в лог "К серверу стукнулся клиент 192.168.1.15".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определяем слот **ip()** и делаем "поиск хоста" по доменному имени с помощью **QHostInfo::lookupHost()**. Если найден в сети такой домен, то вызывается слот, которому передаётся информация о домене, в частности список ip-адресов, связанных с ним.

```
QHostInfo::lookupHost(hostname, this, SLOT(ip(const QHostInfo&)));
void Model::ip(const QHostInfo& hostInfo)
{
    const auto ip = hostInfo.addresses().first().toString();
}
```